# Git remove only push last local commit

Tags: git, git-reset

I have made a bunch of changes on my local git version of a Rails project that I don't want to lose, however in doing so, I accidentally created a **vendor/bundle** folder in Git.

I realized as soon as I committed that I did this and did a git rm for the folder (and added the folder to gitignore), and committed again. However, now I can't push the original because the bundle is too large.

#### What I need

- How can I keep the edits (and new files) I made.
- While removing the bundle folder from git history
- And not pushing that commit with them since the directory is too large

I've been searching SO for various ways of soft resetting here, but I'm stuck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do `git reset --soft HEAD~x` where x is the number of review you want to reset - 2 in your case and then add the directory to the gitignore file and also remove it from the staged area.

Comment: I tried that (and then the answer I made on this thread) and got the same rejected because of an individual file in that directory. Going to keep digging.

Comment: I ended up having to go back further in the local commits, but this did it. The other option I listed as an answer could work if your directories are in git repos as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

> This occurs fairly commonly. Someone accidentally commits a huge
>   binary file with a thoughtless git add ., and you want to remove it
>   everywhere. Perhaps you accidentally committed a file that contained a
>   password, and you want to make your project open source. filter-branch
>   is the tool you probably want to use to scrub your entire history. To
>   remove a file named passwords.txt from your entire history, you can
>   use the --tree-filter option to filter-branch:

[Source](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Splitting-a-Commit):

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f /vendor/bundle' HEAD`